# Connect Docker Container port to server's apache port (odoo Container)

Tags: apache, docker, server, odoo

I have downloaded the Odoo container and I want to docker run it inside my server and gain access from outside. This means I want to run the container in localhost:8069 and gain access from :8000 (8000 is an open port and apache2 serves from it). Is this possible?

Comment: When Apache http server (or any other process) is listening on port 8000 no other application/process can bind to the same port.
You can set up a reverse proxy on your Apache and forward the requests from a specific context path on port 8000 to the port that your container is listening to.

Comment: Wow, just saw that this question was asked ages ago.

Answer (score 0):

To allow Dockerized services to be access from outside you can use the option `--publish` of the command `docker run`

> From the man page:
>
> ```
>   -p, --publish=[]
>       Publish a container's port, or range of ports, to the host.
>   Format: ip:hostPort:containerPort | ip::containerPort | hostPort:containerPort | containerPort Both hostPort and containerPort can be specified as a range of ports.  When specifying ranges for both, the number of container ports in the range must match the number of host ports in the range.  (e.g., docker run -p 1234-1236:1222-1224 --name thisWorks -t busybox but not docker  run  -p 1230-1236:1230-1240  --name  RangeContainerPortsBiggerThanRangeHostPorts  -t busybox) With ip: docker run -p 127.0.0.1:$HOSTPORT:$CONTAINERPORT --name CONTAINER -t someimage Use docker port to see the actual mapping: docker port CONTAINER $CONTAINERPORT
> ```

Then running: `docker run -p 1.2.3.4:8000:80 image-name` will bind the socket `1.2.3.4:8000` of the server to the port `80` of the container.

Comment: I have one port open 8000 in which apache files are located and odoo serves in 8069, how can I access the VM from port 8000 and get redirected to port 8069 without stopping apache?

Comment: Does your VM port is accessible from outside? Your needs are unclear and your setup description is confusing. Could you edit the question and make it as clear as possible please (including what is the VM host, where is the Docker Daemon, where does apache run, from where the apache server should be accessible and to which socket of which server/VM/docker, etc.) ?

Comment: My VM is only accesible from port 8000. The Odoo docker serves at 8069 port. Apache runs at 8000. So I need a way to go type a URL like http://odoo.domain.com:8000 and get redirected to http://odoo.domain.com:8069. I dont understand what a socket is so I can't give you this info.

Comment: What is the physical host responding to the odoo.domain.com domain name? I guess it is the VM host. As your Docker is inside the VM and that "_[the] VM is only accesible from port 8000_" then the odoo.domain.com:8069 wouldn't offer access to the Dockerized service.

Comment: This is what I want to say. Is it possible to offer access to 8069 port through 8000 port in which apache is running?

Comment: Nope, you'll need to open up another port.